# PushViewController Leads To Black Screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

```
SettingsViewController *viewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

When using this code in a NavigationController the scene shown is just a black screen. In storyboard it shows the content but it is not displayed on the phone.

Comment: Please note that if you are not using ARC then you are leaking viewController.

Comment: Say `animated:NO`.  (Facing the same problem, only on iOS 7.)

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
SettingsViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"setting"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Set the settingviewcontroller's identifier to "setting"

Comment: Rather than get a storyboard using a hard-coded name, it's possible to get the storyboard that the navController came from using `self.navigationController.storyboard` and eliminating the first line.

Comment: ok.. Thanks for your great suggestion. We can also use self.view.storyboard for this.. Happy Coding :)

Comment: self.navigationController.storyboard was causing the issue in my case, in swift

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
SettingsViewController *viewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do it is by instantiate with the storyboard. You must give your viewcontroller a Storyboard ID and then use the following code:

```
YourView *view = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourViewID"];
```

When this is done simply push:

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  SettingsViewController *viewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by custom initialisation of destination view controller.

Your destination view controller:

```
-(id) initWithSender:(UINavigationController*)sender
{
        self=[sender.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DestinationVCIdentifier"];
    if (self) {
        //custom initialisation
    }
    return self;
}
```

And using it:

```
DestinationVC *viewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithSender:self.navigationController];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: initWithSender method does not exist.

Comment: @Dejan yep, if you did not add it into your view controller

Answer (score 0):

Hi You've to set the top bar property (navigation bar) to **inferred** for the view controller. In my case I previously set the top bar as *"Translucent navigation bar"*

Usually this happens you perform a segue from a modal view controller.

Answer (score 0):

so you could initialise using the name of the xib or storyboard as everyone is suggesting and that’s valid.

Although if you’re using storyboards and your initial viewcontroller is on the storyboard, they maybe rather do the following,

```
// Method in your initial viewcontroller 
- (void)youPushMethod { 

// Name your segue on your storyboard, e.g. SegueIndentifier 
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueIndentifier" sender:self];
}
```

Then,

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@“SegueIndentifier"]) {
     SettingsViewController *settingsViewController= segue.destinationViewController;
    }
}
```