# instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier in xcode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

I'm working on a storyboard in xcode 5. I have a navigation controller, and am trying to establish the transitions to other scenes in my storyboard. I first tried using:

```
- (IBAction)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
NSLog(@"Image clicked");

_detailPage = [[MPDetailPageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MPDetailPageViewController" bundle:nil];
_detailPage.product = _curProduct;

//Bring to detail page
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailPage animated:YES];
}
```

This would bring me to a black screen. Searching on stackoverflow I found [this post from Feb 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929039/pushviewcontroller-leads-to-black-screen) which suggested using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`

So I tried:

```
- (IBAction)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
NSLog(@"Image clicked");

_detailPage = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MPDetailPageViewController"];
_detailPage.product = _curProduct;

//Bring to detail page
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailPage animated:YES];
}
```

However, this gave me an error

> Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'MPDetailPageViewController'

I tried figuring out how to find/ set the identifier and saw posts referencing `Storyboard ID`, but when I look on my screen I only see `Restoration ID` and I can only see that when I click on the `View` and not the `ViewController` itself. When I click on the `ViewController`, I don't see `Restoration ID` nor `Storyboard ID`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `Storyboard ID` property can be found in the `Identity Inspector` of the View Controller:

1. Open up your storyboard.
2. Click on the **black bar** underneath the view you've designed to display your details.
3. Make sure you have the `Identity Inspector` open on the right.  It's the third icon at the top when you have the `Utilities` pane open.
4. The second section in the `Identity Inspector` is labeled "Identity".  The first property listed is `Storyboard ID`.  You can set the value of it to "MPDetailPageViewController".

EDIT:  Added screen shot:
[image]

Comment: Oh, this is embarrassing.  My "Identity" section was just minimized.  had to click on it to display "Storyboard ID" and "Restoration ID".  Thanks for your help!